# Gradle: copy web-inf/libs to root of war

Tags: java, applet, gradle, war

I'm converting an old project which uses applets to gradle from ant.  My issue lies that I need to be able to copy my lib folder from web-inf to the base of the war so that my applets can access the jars.  I've tried using a move task but that doesn't seem to affect the directories inside of the war task.  Could someone offer any assistence, I tried doing a task that runs the following:

```
from configurations.runtime
into "$buildDir/lib"
```

This seems to only affect my $buildDir/lib folder, not the root directory inside of my war. I'm assuming there is a similar command I can add to the war task for it to work?

Comment: Do you want the Jars in the root of the War or under `lib/`? Do you also want them in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: I want a folder on the root of the war that would contain every jar that my web-inf lib contains.  When I put the following into my war task:  from(configurations.compile) { into "lib"}  the files move but for some reason I cannot open any of the jars (jar -tvf gives an error in opening zip file)

Comment: It would have to be `war { from(configurations.runtime) }`. (You need all runtime dependencies, and you said you want them in the root rather than in a `lib` directory.) Not sure what you mean by "move", as  there will still be a `WEB-INF/lib`. I can't say why you wouldn't be able to open the Jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring all your jars to `rootdir/libs` in that way :

```
war {
    // bring all jars to RootDir/libs
    from(configurations.runtime) {
        into 'libs'
    }
}
```